# ng-show not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-show

so i have the following code:

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
         alert('form is valid!');
    };
});

<body ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<form name="newTaskForm" ng-submit="submitForm(newTaskForm.$valid)" novalidate>

<input type="text" list="Topics" name="Topic" placeholder="Topic" ng-model="topic" required>
<p ng-show="newTaskForm.topic.$invalid">Please enter a valid Topic</p>
```

i am trying to get the message to show up but it just doesn't, i've inspected the element and all, and the classes do change for the input text, however ng-show just doesn't budge, it starts off as hidden, and just stays hidded, and i have tried other bg-show conditions, to no avail :/

i've only included the parts of code i think matter... for simplicity's sake.

this is still day one of my angularJS 'adventure' so it could be a very simple mistake, but i've been on it for the last hour and have no idea what's wrong.

any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: change `newTaskForm.topic.$invalid` to `newTaskForm.Topic.$invalid`, since your `name="Topic"`.

Comment: well that's embarrassing.. thanks a million :) i'm still getting the hang of angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have done a silly mistake.use this code:

```
<input type="text" list="Topics" name="Topic" placeholder="Topic" ng-model="topic" required>
                <p ng-show="newTaskForm.Topic.$invalid">Please enter a valid Topic</p>
```

or use this:

```
<input type="text" list="Topics" name="Topic" placeholder="Topic" ng-model="topic" required>
                <p ng-show="newTaskForm.$invalid">Please enter a valid Topic</p>
```

here you have done naming mistake. validation is done using the name of the field. here input field has name **Topic**. so use  newTaskForm.Topic.$invalid inside ng-show like this:

```
ng-show="newTaskForm.Topic.$invalid"
```